# Boton con JQuery usar atributo como nombre del boton

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buenas necesito que el atributo **PRECIO** que este en la etiqueta **A** se use como **VALOR** en el **INPUT**.

Logre hacerlo pero se mantiene estático, al principio lo había logrado desde el `input` y recorría cada botón pero al implantarlo en el proyecto donde estoy trabajando tiene que ser desde la etiqueta `<a>` entonces ya logre hacerlo pero caí en el mismo problema, no hace el ciclo se mantiene solo en el primer botón.

Aquí muestro lo que llevo, soy nuevo en la programación apenas, espero puedan ayudarme y entender lo que trato de decir, tiene que ser de ese modo porque en el proyecto donde estoy el usuario puede modificar el atributo mediante una caja de texto por ahora estoy trabajando que sean valores fijos.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<a id="inq4" producto="Producto 1" precio="123"> <input type="submit" value="" /></a>
<a id="inq5" producto="Producto 2" precio="456"> <input type="submit" value="" /></a>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
      $("input").attr("value", $("a").attr("precio") + ' $');
    });
  });
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En programación existe el concepto de `this` que en el caso de la función `each()` hace referencia a cada uno de los elementos de la colección capturada con `$('input')`. De esta manera, podemos hacer que por cada `<input>`, busque a su padre (la etiqueta `<a>` en nuestro caso) y extraiga su valor del atributo *precio*).

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    
    <a id="inq4" producto="Producto 1" precio="123" >  <input type="submit" value=""/></a>
    <a id="inq5" producto="Producto 2" precio="456"> <input type="submit" value=""/></a>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("value", $(this).parent().attr("precio") + ' $');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que quedaría mejor si en lugar de usar atributos "libres" colocas toda la información en [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: Sería mejor, para eso están los atributos personalizados de HTML5. No lo añadí porque según el **OP** dice necesita de esa estructura en su proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias :) es justamente lo que andaba necesitando, gracias por tu explicación y la brevedad en responderme amigo <3